# why ajax call url ends with #.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    cache: 'false',
    url:"/foo/",
    data:{"id": pid},
    success:function(data) {
         $('#wrapper').html(data);
    }
});

<li id="btn-click" class="select">{{ promo.name }}</li>
```

Why ajax url ends with `#.`
Suppose My url is `http://localhost:8000/foo/` then it ends with `http://localhost:8000/foo/#.`
I don't want to use #. at the last.

Comment: What? Maybe you have href="#" on the link that runs the ajax call?

Comment: could you post all of your code here, the above is missing the click handler for #btn-click (i suppose) as well as the complete html containing #wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your anchor have a # in it so that it doesn't reload the page? If so, on your click event you will need to either return: false; or use event.stopPropagation(); to prevent the default behaviour.

What is the value of {{ promo.name }} ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have href="#" on the link that runs the ajax call?
use href="javascript:void(0)" instead.

Comment: The whole point of jQuery is to remove the necessity for adding inline javascript, and javascript in the href attribute is certainly not a practice I would be teaching someone these days. That control can be handled inside the function attached to the anchor, in which you can use the method I posted above